# Prove for all $1<n\in \mathbb{N}$ there are infinity natural numbers $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \dfrac{\varphi(t)}{t}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove for all $1<n\in \mathbb{N}$ there are infinity natural numbers $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \dfrac{\varphi(t)}{t}$.

we know that $$n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$$

therefore, $$\varphi(n) = n(1-\dfrac{1}{p_1})\cdots (1-\dfrac{1}{p_k})$$

so, $$\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\dfrac{1}{p_i})$$

that's means $$\varphi(t)=\dfrac{t\cdot\varphi(n)}{n}=t\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\dfrac{1}{p_i})$$

Comment: the product converges to zero what can you say about the nuber of points

Comment: You are on the right track, you can see from the last equation how you can choose the $t$'s.

Comment: The senetence "Prove for all $1<n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n} $" does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there! If $p_1,..., p_k$ are the primes dividing $n$, you just said that

$$ \frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \prod_{i=1}^k \left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right) $$

Hence, to get $\phi(n)/n = \phi(t)/t$ you need $t$ to be divisible by exactly the same primes as $n$. If $n = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i ^{\alpha_i}$ (where $\alpha_i > 0$) then you need $t = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\beta_i}$ for $\beta_i > 0$.

Comment: well, yes You can choose the $\beta_i$ in infinitely many ways